# How UITableView working without registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In `stroryboard` I have `UIViewController` which contains `UITableView` and inside that I created a dynamic `UITableViewCell` and give it an identifier.

In `UIViewController` in `cellforrowatindexpath` method I simply did `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]`.

I did **not** use `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` but my app is working perfectly.

How without `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` app is working and cells are dequeueing perfectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cell definition for that identifier is specified in the storyboard, during compilation this is converted into an NIB and during unarchiving the cell NIB is registered with the table view.

Answer (score 1):

```
registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:
```

---

*This method is only used when you are using custom class for your cell in tableview, currently you have defined a prototype cell which automatically  uses default UITableViewCell class, and you have to access the cell properties with tag value, but in case of custom class you make property or outlet for the labels/textviews/imageviews in `CustomCell.h` and you have to register the Class with a unique Identifier name at time of loading the ViewController, so that tableview can understand at runtime  which cell class should be loaded  as per the cell identifier used in storyboard.*

Answer (score 0):

> **Discussion**
>
> Before dequeueing any cells, call this method or the
> registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method to tell the table view
> how to create new cells. If a cell of the specified type is not
> currently in a reuse queue, the table view uses the provided
> information to create a new cell object automatically.
>
> If you previously registered a class or nib file with the same reuse
> identifier, the nib you specify in the nib parameter replaces the old
> entry. You may specify nil for nib if you want to unregister the nib
> from the specified reuse identifier.

If You are using separate UITableViewCell class or xib file for UITableviewCell ContentView, where the UIElements are access through the class file. In Storyboard the UITableViewDataSource get the cell by its identifier.

```
UINib *sectionHeaderNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"Header" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:sectionHeaderNib forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];
// [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"]; // register your your UITableView Class
```

Check the [LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) Project
and [UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:)